# Listview not refreshing after page change (WPF C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am currently working on a program in wpf that requires use of listview and being able to leave a page, go to menu, then return to the page where it displays different data.

The first time the page is opened the code works fine, and the list view works and refreshes as normal, when I leave the page and later return to it however, the listview is broken and doesn't display any of my data.

```
if (!CompareChats(AllMessages, OldMessages))
{
    MessageDisplayList.ItemsSource = AllMessages;
    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MessageDisplayList.Items);
    view.Refresh();
    if (AllMessages.Count > 0)
    {
        if (AllMessages[AllMessages.Count - 1].MessageAQ != Environment.UserName)
        {
            Global_Class.NotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = PrevData.Identifier + ": " + AllMessages[AllMessages.Count - 1].MessageText + " (" + AllMessages[AllMessages.Count - 1].MessageSender + ")";
            Global_Class.NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(2500);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using ICollectionView and MessageList.Items.Refresh() but both encounter the same bug, I've been through the program via breakpoints and the ItemsSource is set and holds the data so I can only assume it must be a bug with the following command, any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solved Issue, Needed to refresh in the main part of the page to start off with, working fine now